# JavaFX Java17 - exit Fullscreen Event

Tags: java, javafx

I have added a custom toolbar (where my window actions are placed) to my application. So far everything works well. Related to the window handling I'm searching for a possibility to handle the "fullscreen got closed" event. Scenario:
App starts in windowed mode -> user clicks on (custom) toolbar button to get into fullscreen. The Toolbar will now be set its visibility to false. The users now exits fullscreen mode via button (native macOS Button to exit fullscreen) --> I need now to react for this (to set the toolbar to visible again) but cannot find a way how to do it.

main.java

```
MainController mc = new MainController();
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("welcome-view.fxml"));
stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
mc.doSwitchScenes(stage, root);
stage.show();
```

MainController.java

```
...
private String title = "Project Apollo";
private Color fillColor = TRANSPARENT;
private int minWidth = 800;
private int minHeight = 600;
...

public void btnMinimize(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
    Stage stage = (Stage)((Circle)mouseEvent.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
    // is stage minimizable into task bar. (true | false)
    stage.setIconified(true);
};

public void btnCloseApp(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
    Platform.exit();
    System.exit(0);
}

public void btnFullscreen(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
    Stage stage = (Stage)((Circle)mouseEvent.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
    stage.setFullScreen(true);
    Scene actualScene = ((Node)mouseEvent.getSource()).getScene();
    Parent hbc = (Parent) actualScene.lookup("#headerBarContainer");

    if(hbc != null){
        hbc.setVisible(false);
    }
    System.out.println("clicked FS");

}
...
```

The point is that at least on MacOS the window has its native os control to exit fullscreen - is it possible to target this event or at least the change of the stage size maybe?

Comment: how about reading the api doc of stage/window as a first step ;) If applying what you learned from isn't working as you expect it, next step is to provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem. BTW: you loading snippet looks fishy - assuming that MainController is-a class that's loaded with its fields/handlers injected via fxml. If that assumption is wrong, you might consider naming it to someting other than xxController to not confuse the readers :)

Comment: @kleopatra - thanks for your feedback - i'm in the early stages with Java & my JavaFX skills are only a few weeks old. For sure you're right RTMF but i was not able to find a solution by the given information from school / docs. c0der was gently enough to show me that there is a way to detect changes by adding a listener to stageProps which is nice becaus i did not realized that before. And yes the Controller got its fields injected by fxml - yes the FXML tag was missing in this stage of dev but was added some minutes ago ;-) - Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: About `MainController`: You're creating your own instance and then calling a method on it. That should not work as you expect. If you're using `fx:controller` in the FXML file then the `FXMLLoader` will instantiate `MainController` for you, via reflection. Thus, the instance of `MainController` that you created is not the same instance which had its fields injected and such. If you want access to the controller instance created by the `FXMLLoader`, then create an **instance** of `FXMLLoader` and use the **instance** `load` method, followed by the `getController()` method.

Comment: oh! Thanks @Slaw i missed that completely - it still works in this stage of dev but you're totally right i will get into problems. I have to rework this part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listen to `stage.fullScreenProperty()` and respond to changes:

```
stage.fullScreenProperty().addListener((ChangeListener) (obs,oldValue,newValue) -> 
                                          {/*TODO respond to changes in full screen */;});
```

Comment: thanks - works like a charm and is way better then my approach with a changelistener for scene height and width